# Navigation Bar Back Button pushes everthing to the right

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm having trouble with xaml, the trouble is that I want a center the image on the Navigation Bar

In this image its achived but When i send the user to another page using a button i.e. sign up using c#

```
 async void ButtonSignup_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new SignupPage());
        }
```

[now moving to image two this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6kvQ.png)

[The centre image is pushed to the right, but wanted centred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TK4u.png)

Code for the nav bar

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="10">
            <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1.0" Source="assets/Images/diamond.png"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

At this point I'm out of ideas, Ive tried margins different tags of xaml but none  have worked.

Comment: Cfun, thank you doing this via mobile phone can be a pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_gravity` in toolbar. It would make the image in the center without affect of back button.

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```

The whole code of toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"

>
<ImageView         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/diamond_16px"/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

MainActivity:

```
 ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
```

OutPut:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
        <Image Source="assets/Images/diamond.png" />          
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Found it here by James Montemagno

```
https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-icons-in-navigation-toolbar/
```